# ASP.NET :is there a limit for parameter length in querystring?

Tags: asp.net

I have a problem when passing parameters in querystring. I found that its values are null.
Below my code snippet:

page1 - here I am passing some parameters:

```
Response.Redirect(string.Format("RequestReservationPage.aspx?plcName={0}&PLCIndex={1}&Email={2}&form={3}&to={4}&SR={5}&Comment={6}", lblPLCNameVal.Text, index, lblEmailVal.Text, DateTime.Parse(lblReqFromVal.Text).ToShortDateString(),DateTime.Parse(lblReqToVal.Text).ToShortDateString(), lblServReqNum.Text, lblYourCommentVal.Text));
```

page2 - here I am requesting its values:

```
cmbPLCRequest.SelectedIndex = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["PLCIndex"]);

txtEmail.Text = Convert.ToString(Request.QueryString["Email"]);
txtSR.Text = Convert.ToString(Request.QueryString["SR"]);           
txtComment.Text = Convert.ToString(Request.QueryString["Comment"]);
txtReqFromDate.Text =Request.QueryString["from"];
txtReqToDate.Text = Request.QueryString["to"];
```

but I found that both of Request.QueryString["from"] and Request.QueryString["to"] return null

any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two problems: typo in the `from` - in the Redirect code you got it as `form`.
Also, you better encode all the values to be fit for URL.. so the code will be:

```
Response.Redirect(string.Format("RequestReservationPage.aspx?plcName={0}&PLCIndex={1}&Email={2}&from={3}&to={4}&SR={5}&Comment={6}", 
   Server.UrlEncode(lblPLCNameVal.Text), 
   index, 
   Server.UrlEncode(lblEmailVal.Text), 
   Server.UrlEncode(DateTime.Parse(lblReqFromVal.Text).ToShortDateString()), 
   Server.UrlEncode(DateTime.Parse(lblReqToVal.Text).ToShortDateString()), 
   Server.UrlEncode(lblServReqNum.Text), Server.UrlEncode(lblYourCommentVal.Text)));
```

Answer (score 3):

see [this](http://www.asp101.com/tips/index.asp?id=102)

> The amount of data you can transfer on
>   the QueryString is limited by a number
>   of factors, but the one that seems to
>   be the most restrictive is the space
>   in your browser's address bar. The
>   Internet Explorer versions 5 and 6
>   that I tested only allowed up to 2,047
>   characters while Netscape Navigator
>   version 4 seemed to be able to handle
>   up to 30,000 and I couldn't get
>   version 6 much past 9,000.

See this [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6c3yckfw.aspx) article for other options instead of passing variables by using the querystring

EDIT: try storing your values in the POST parameters if you need large strings

Comment: i am using IE ver8...so how could i get rid off this?any idea will be appreciated